# Float a span left within an unordered list item, even when the line breaks

Tags: css, list, css-float

I am trying to get a span to *always* float left within an unordered list item. The code below works fine, until I make the browser width narrow enough to force a line break within the list item - then "the date" no longer appears first. how can I get this span to always appear first ?

```
<ul class="post-title">
<li> - this is the text. this is the text. this is the text.  <span style="float:left">the date</span>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 0):

what about putting the span first

```
<ul class="post-title">
<li><span style="float:left">the date</span> - this is the text. this is the text. this is the text.  
</ul>
```

Comment: I am trying to use css to style the PHP output of a plug-in, in which the date is shown last, so I am not able to change the order of the items : https://github.com/picandocodigo/List-Category-Posts/issues/226

Answer (score 0):

you can enclose both *-this is the text....* and *the date* to `span`.

```
<ul class="post-title">
  <li> 
      <span>the date</span>
      <span>- this is the text. this is the text. this is the text </span>  
  </li>
</ul>
```

so that the date will always appear first.

No need for  `style="float:left"`.

Comment: please see my comment on the answer above

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if there is a css solution for this but if you want to use **jquery** then try this..

```js
var span = $('span');
span.remove();
$('li').prepend(span);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul class="post-title">
<li> - Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum.<span>the date</span></li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this one.

```css
li,ul{
                list-style: none;
                margin: 0;
                padding: 0;
                font-size: 20px
            }
            li{
                position: relative;
                text-indent: 70px;
            }
            span{
                position: absolute;
                background: red;
                left: 0;
                top: 0;
                width: 70px;
                text-indent: 0;
            }
```

```html
<ul class="post-title">
    <li> - this is the text. this is the text. this is the text.  <span>the date</span>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for all of your help. After struggling to make a CSS solution work well, I was able to solve the issue by creating a custom php template for the plug-in: https://github.com/picandocodigo/List-Category-Posts/tree/master/templates